# React-Redux ailed propType - value undefined

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to use propTypes to help typeCheck/validate data in my app. The data comes through fine but I get a warning; `Warning: Failed prop type: The prop`allSubjectSubcategories`is marked as required in`OddMainPage`, but its value is`undefined`.

I've read through some of the other responses but I haven't yet fpound a solution to fix my issues.

COMPONENT

```
class OddMainPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            categoryTables: [],
            tableColumns: [],

            gettingColumns: false,
            selectedCategory: "",
            selectedTable: ""
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(getAllSubjectSubCategories());
    }

  //more code to render some data
}}

OddMainPage.propTypes = {
    allSubjectSubcategories: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    subCategoryTables: PropTypes.array,
    tableColumns: PropTypes.array
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    allSubjectSubcategories: state.allSubjectSubcategories.allSubjectSubcategories,
    subCategoryTables: state.subCategoryTables.subCategoryTables,
    tableColumns: state.tableColumns.tableColumns
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OddMainPage);
```

REDUCER

```
const initialState = {
    subCategoryTables: [],
    allSubjectCategories: [],
    allSubjectSubcategories: []
}

export const getAllSubjectSubcategoriesReducer = (state = initialState.allSubjectSubcategories, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_ALL_SUBJECT_SUBCATEGORIES":
            return {
                ...state,
                allSubjectSubcategories: action.allSubCats
            }
        default:
            return initialState.allSubjectSubcategories
    }
}
```

I also tried setting default state to `default: return state` but get the same results.

STORE

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

let store;

if (window.navigator.userAgent.includes("Chrome")) {
  store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
  );
} else {
  store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
  );
}

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're changing the return type of your reducer form an array to an object on the `GET_ALL_SUBJECT_SUBCATEGORIES` action.

Looking at `initialState` for `getAllSubcategoriesReducer`, you can see the value is an array. However the return value for the `GET_ALL_SUBJECT_SUBCATEGORIES` branch is an object. You'll need to standardize on one or the other.

Since the initial state of the reducer is just an empty array, the value of `state.allSubjectSubcategories` in `mapStateToProps` will be that empty array. So when you call `allSubjectSubcategories: state.allSubjectSubcategories.allSubjectSubcategories,` you get `undefined`.

If you want to keep the nested version you will need to change `initialState` (and fix the default case of the reducer):

```
// NOTE: I've nested all of your sub-reducer keys to match your `mapStateToProps`.
const initialState = {
    subCategoryTables: {
      subCategoryTables: [],
    },
    allSubjectCategories: {
      allSubjectCategories: [],
    },
    allSubjectSubcategories: {
      allSubjectSubcategories: [],
    }
}


export const getAllSubjectSubcategoriesReducer = (state = initialState.allSubjectSubcategories, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_ALL_SUBJECT_SUBCATEGORIES":
            return {
                ...state,
                allSubjectSubcategories: action.allSubCats
            }
        // return `state` here or you will keep reseting your reducer state
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the reducer as an array like the initial state you will need to update your reducer and your `mapStateToProps`:

```
export const getAllSubjectSubcategoriesReducer = (state = initialState.allSubjectSubcategories, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_ALL_SUBJECT_SUBCATEGORIES":
            // assuming action.allSubCats is an array, we want to replace this entire reducer state with the new array
            return action.allSubCats
        // return `state` here or you will keep reseting your reducer state
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Now that the reducer above always returns an array you can update your `mapStateToProps` to remove the extra key being introduced before:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    allSubjectSubcategories: state.allSubjectSubcategories,  // note the change here
    // you probably want these to be updated as well with similar changes to your other reducers
    subCategoryTables: state.subCategoryTables,
    tableColumns: state.tableColumns
})
```

Comment: Thanks @azundo, If I choose the 2nd option and keep resetting the reducer state - isn't that mutating an immutable state? And therefore an anti-react patern?

Comment: Do you mean because option 2 is returning `action.allSubCats` directly? In that case the state is being replaced entirely, not being mutated, which is fine. Mutation is a problem in redux when the value of part of your state changes without the reference to that value changing. For example if you mutated the `state` array by pushing new values into it instead of returning a completely new array. If you're worried about some other code mutating `action.allSubCats` elsewhere you could `return [...action.allSubCats];` to make a shallow copy.

Comment: THank you @Azundo for the clarification